# Removing newlines in a DataFrame field with udf function gives TypeTag Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

```
val trim: String => String = _.trim.replace("[\\r\\n]", "")

def main(args: Array[String]) {    
    val spark = ...    ...
    import spark.implicits._    
    val trimUDF = udf[String,String](trim)

    val df = spark.read.json(df_path)    ...    
    val fixed_dblogs_df = df.withColumn("qp_new", trimUDF('qp))    ... 
}
```

When I run this code I get a compile time error:

> No TypeTag available for String

This error is where I define the udf function. I have no idea why this is happening. I have used udf functions before but this one is making this error. I used Spark 2.1.1 and that's it.

The purpose of the code is to remove all the new lines in one of my fields of columns that is StringType and I just want it to not have any newlines in it

Comment: please show a reproducible example

Comment: You defined your function as `trim` but in the udf, you are using `betterTrimmer`?

Comment: Sorry in order to make it readable I removed some lines, and renamed some variables. I'm just reading a dataframe that has a field of string type and I only want to remove the end of lines in that string field. I also fixed the trim function

Comment: I removed betterTrimmer. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some reason you're using a UDF instead of the `replace_regexp` builtin?

```
val fixed_dblogs_df = df.withColumn("qp_new", replace_regexp('qp, "[\\r\\n]", "") ...)
```

UDF's break Spark's plan optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will test it but I do not understand why the udf is giving me this error specially since I'm using udf for a lot more after this to get the schema out of that string.

Comment: Do you have reference for udf breaking optimizations and what is the right way for column manipulation?

Comment: From the Cloudera blog: "Another important component of Spark SQL to be aware of is the Catalyst query optimizer. Its capabilities are expanding with every release and can often provide dramatic performance improvements to Spark SQL queries; however, arbitrary UDF implementation code may not be well understood by Catalyst (although future features which analyze bytecode are being considered to address this).  As such, using Spark’s built-in SQL query functions will often lead to the best performance and should be the **first approach considered** whenever introducing a UDF can be avoided."

Comment: Shouldn't it be regexp_replace instead of replace_regexp?